# Push css table cell out of browser window

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm working on a layout where different cells in a css table are supposed to push each other out of the browser window, if their size increases. The content of the cells is dynamically loaded via ajax. It's difficult to describe, so I made a sketch:

This is the initial state of the css table:

[image: initial state]

If cell 1 increases in width, it is supposed to go beyond the browser window:
[image: initial state]

But if cell 3 increases in width, it is supposed to push the other cells beyond the browser window:
[image: initial state]

I hope this makes it clear, if not I will try to describe it in more detail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: I tried putting the content of cell 1 inside a div with display:flex. This works for step 2 but not for step 3, also not for Internet Explorer.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having? Without seeing your code we can't really offer you any help, or any insight into your assumptions or mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
#parent {
  background-color: khaki;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  /* comment it out to remove the scrollbar */
  overflow: auto;
}

#left-child {
  margin: 50px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: coral;
  height: 100px;
  order: 3;
  /* change min-width to change the width of the div */
  min-width: 1000px;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
}
#middle-child {
  margin: 50px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  order: 2;
  /* change min-width to change the width of the div */
  min-width: 1000px;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
}
#right-child {
  margin: 50px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100px;
  order: 1;
  /* change min-width to change the width of the div */
  min-width: 1000px;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left-child"></div>
  <div id="middle-child"></div>
  <div id="right-child"></div>
</div>
```

go to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dbkomah/) and try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! This helps a lot!

Comment: @Julius glad to help. btw you can make the answer accepted it will be helpfull for others to find the answer !